# Ruby on Rails - Remove slug uniqueness from Friendly_id slug in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

I use `Friendly_id gem` in my application. In my `Slide` model, I don't need `slug` to be unique, as it's never duplicated (it's auto generated)

How can I remove `slug`**uniqueness** from my `slides` database.

This is what I have: `index_slides_on_slug_and_post_id` and `slug` is `:unique => true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to do it in a rails migration, you should be able to remove the index and then add it back without the unique constraint.

Something similar to this should do the trick

```
class ChangeSlugIndex < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_index(:slides, name: 'index_slides_on_slug_and_post_id')
    add_index(:slides, [:slug,:post_id], name: 'index_slides_on_slug_and_post_id')
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Doon for your answer